# EOL Error while concatenating string to generate path location in Python

Tags: python, concatenation, filepath

I want to write to a csv file at a location. While generating location of path, I get extra back slash :

```
file= 'alpha.txt'
location= 'C:\\Python\Project'
path= location +'\\' +file
path
```

Output: "C:\\Python\\Project\\alpha.txt"

**Expected Output:** 'C:\Python\Project\alpha.txt'

Comment: Do `location = r'C:\Python\Project'` and `path = location + r'\' + file`

Comment: Backslash is the escape character and you encode that in a string by typing it twice.  If you print it, you will see it looks right, i.e. `print(path)`.

Comment: @pavel `r'\'` would give an error. `\\` is still a potential escape character in raw strings in case you want to add the quotes in the string.

Comment: @AllanWind i want to call path, so that i can write into alpha.txt file. Extra backslash does not recognize the path

Comment: @Ussu20 **print** (`print(path)`) the string there are no extra backslashes. When you just write `path` in the interpreter it prints the string with quotes and shows how the string would have been written in code.

Comment: i have some data say stored in DataFrame. Suppose, i want to write to data in the path: data.to_csv(print(path). It does not work as expected. Neither does data.to_csv('print(path)')